# MOC a lambda connection

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, moc

I'd like to create a connection like so:

```
connect(myMap[myObjectName], &myObject::valueChanged, [&] (int value)
{
    QString objectName = sender()->objectName();
    myOtherMap[objectName].setValue(QVariant(value));
});
```

This doesn't work though because sender() can't be invoked without the function going through the MOC. Thus, the only way to make this work (seemingly) is using the old signal/slot string based syntax.

However, things like [this Qt blog](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/06/22/changes-to-the-meta-object-system-in-qt-5/%20this%20Qt%20blog) make it seem like the Qt5 function pointer syntax should be preferred over the previous string syntax, so I'm curious: is there is some way to MOC the lamda function, or is there a whole class of cases where the new syntax can't be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` (or any other `QObject`) as a receiver to make `sender()` method work:

```
connect(myMap[myObjectName], &myObject::valueChanged, this, [&] (int value)
{
    QString objectName = sender()->objectName();
    myOtherMap[objectName].setValue(QVariant(value));
});
```

Or take a look at [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html). It looks like a good fit for your scenario.

Comment: Qsignalmapper is not a good fit as it doesn't allow for functions with parameters. I'll check out the rest tomorrow when I get in to work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on myMap, something like this should work:

auto &x = myMap[myObjectName]
connect(x, &myObject::valueChanged, [&] (int value) { x.setValue(QVariant(value)); });

Comment: can you explain why that will invoke MOC?